# Regex domain with TLD or localhost

Tags: regex

Basically, a user can map my music app to one of these posibilities:

- `{subdomain}.{domain}.localhost`
- `{domain}.localhost`
- `localhost`

Basically, I need to extract in Regex `localhost` or `{domain}.localhost`, even if the user access at `{subdomain}.{domain}.localhost`. Kinda lost with regex.

So:

```
mymusic.homemusic.localhost --> homemusic.localhost
homemusic.localhost --> homemusic.localhost
localhost --> localhost
```

Edit: I'm using #!/bin/sh

Comment: why not just cutting the string on the last dot?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using  #!/bin/sh

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for this? And how?

Comment: Haven't seen the libraries, but the whole point is to later push the hostname to nginx so it can serve the music app on that url.

Answer (score 0):

After some regex, I came with a simple answer:

```
[\w-]+\.?(localhost)?$
```

- `[\w-]` Matches any word, including `-`.
- `+` as many times.
- `\.` Match `.`
- `?` if is present.
- `(localhost)` Match that word
- `?` if is present.
- `$` at the end of the string

There is a lot of more restrictive options (if a user inputs rubish garbage), but this works for me.